# Networking fails after upgrade from Trusty to Xenial

Tags: 16.04, networking

I have upgraded a desktop machine from Trusty to Xenial. After boot, the network interface fails to obtain an IP address.

My `interfaces` file has not changed:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
 metric 10
 up ifconfig eth2 mtu 7152
iface eth2 inet6 auto
```

If I remove `iface eth2 inet6 auto` then the device receives (maintains) an IPv6 address, this is done by the kernel, so at least I have some connectivity.

After boot I notice that `dhclient` has been terminated, yet it has been started during boot (logs follow).

Some facts:

1. All other devices on the network have no trouble obtaining IP addresses (nearly all Linux/Android).
2. Other Xenial (fresh install) machines have no problems, and have the same style of `interfaces` file.
3. The one remaining Trusty machine has no problems; I'm not keen to update that until this is resolved.
4. `sudo service networking restart` gets everything working, so I suspect `systemd` to be the culprit.
5. I do not, and do not wish to use `NetworkManager`. It has never been able to correctly handle my other network devices.
6. I am using a proprietary network driver: the open source driver is unreliable, but I doubt that this is a driver problem because of point 4.
7. `lxcbr0` is brought up separately by `lxc`. This works as expected.

From the `syslog`:

```
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken systemd[1]: Found device RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (RTL8169/8110 Family PCI Gigabit Ethernet NIC).
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken dhclient[548]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
…
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken systemd[1]: Started ifup for eth2.
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken sh[888]: ifup: interface eth2 already configured
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: /bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/bridge
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: Configuring interface lo=lo (inet)
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: /bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/bridge
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: /bin/ip link set dev lo up
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: /bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/clamav-freshclam-ifupdown
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ifmetric
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: /bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/clamav-freshclam-ifupdown
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ifmetric
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken ifup[918]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
…
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken systemd[1]: Starting Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down...
…
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken kernel: [    6.689859] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken kernel: [    6.724978] r8169 0000:02:02.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): not PCI Express
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken kernel: [    6.809724] r8169 0000:02:02.0 eth0: RTL8169sb/8110sb at 0xf8126f00, 80:1f:<snip>, XID 10000000 IRQ 17
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken kernel: [    6.838215] r8169 0000:02:02.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 7152 bytes, tx checksumming: ok]
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken kernel: [    6.874136] r8169 0000:02:02.0 eth2: renamed from eth0
…
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken kernel: [   26.872559] r8169 0000:02:02.0 eth2: link down
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken kernel: [   26.872571] r8169 0000:02:02.0 eth2: link down
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken kernel: [   26.872625] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken kernel: [   29.224117] r8169 0000:02:02.0 eth2: link up
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken kernel: [   29.224149] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth2: link becomes ready
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken kernel: [   29.849186] audit: type=1400 audit(1520435798.058:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=776 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken kernel: [   33.936245] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Mar  7 15:16:46 ken kernel: [   35.074776] bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
…
Mar  7 15:16:49 ken dnsmasq[1614]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
Mar  7 15:16:49 ken dnsmasq-dhcp[1614]: DHCP, IP range 10.0.3.2 -- 10.0.3.254, lease time 1h
Mar  7 15:16:52 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Successfully called chroot().
Mar  7 15:16:52 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Mar  7 15:16:52 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Loading service file /services/apt-cacher-ng.service.
Mar  7 15:16:52 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface lxcbr0.IPv4 with address 10.0.3.1.
Mar  7 15:16:52 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: New relevant interface lxcbr0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Mar  7 15:16:52 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth2.IPv6 with address 2a02:c7f:<snip>.
Mar  7 15:16:52 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: New relevant interface eth2.IPv6 for mDNS.
Mar  7 15:16:52 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Mar  7 15:16:52 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Registering new address record for 10.0.3.1 on lxcbr0.IPv4.
Mar  7 15:16:52 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Registering new address record for 2a02:c7f:<snip> on eth2.*.
Mar  7 15:16:52 ken avahi-dnsconfd[1070]: Successfully connected to Avahi daemon
…
Mar  7 15:16:57 ken ntpd[1996]: Listen normally on 4 eth2 [2a02:c7f:<snip>]:123
Mar  7 15:16:57 ken ntpd[1996]: Listen normally on 5 eth2 [fe80::821f:<snip>%2]:123
```

This doesn't tell me a great deal, other than `eth2` seems to be “already configured”, which it *was* until `dhclient` vanished/died. `ifconfig` confirms that `eth2` is no longer configured / has no IP address assignments.

After issuing `$ sudo service networking restart`:

```
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken systemd[1]: Stopping Raise network interfaces...
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: /bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-down.d
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/clamav-freshclam-ifupdown
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/resolvconf
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/sendmail
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/upstart
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: Configuring interface eth2=eth2 (inet)
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: Terminating ifup (pid 510)
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: /bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-down.d
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/clamav-freshclam-ifupdown
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/resolvconf
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/sendmail
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/upstart
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: /sbin/dhclient -v -r -pf /run/dhclient.eth2.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth2.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.eth2.leases eth2
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken dhclient[3557]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: All rights reserved.
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken dhclient[3557]: Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken dhclient[3557]: Listening on LPF/eth2/80:1f:<snip>
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken dhclient[3557]: Sending on   LPF/eth2/80:1f:<snip>
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: Listening on LPF/eth2/80:1f:<snip>
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: Sending on   LPF/eth2/80:1f:<snip>
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken dhclient[3557]: DHCPRELEASE on eth2 to 192.168.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x353c1ac6)
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: DHCPRELEASE on eth2 to 192.168.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x353c1ac6)
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: send_packet: Network is unreachable
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address.
Mar  7 15:18:31 ken ifdown[3528]: dhclient.c:2474: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: /bin/ip link set dev eth2 down
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Interface eth2.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth2.IPv6 with address 2a02:c7f:<snip>.
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Withdrawing address record for 2a02:c7f:<snip> on eth2.
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: /bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-post-down.d
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/bridge
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/sendmail
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/wireless-tools
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: Configuring interface eth2=eth2 (inet6)
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: /bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-down.d
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/clamav-freshclam-ifupdown
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/resolvconf
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/sendmail
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/upstart
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: /bin/ip -6 addr flush dev eth2 scope global
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: /bin/ip link set dev eth2 down
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: /bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-post-down.d
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/bridge
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/sendmail
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/wireless-tools
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: /bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-post-down.d
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/bridge
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/sendmail
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifdown[3528]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-post-down.d/wireless-tools
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken systemd[1]: Stopped Raise network interfaces.
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: /bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/bridge
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: Configuring interface eth2=eth2 (inet)
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: /bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/bridge
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: /sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth2.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth2.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.eth2.leases eth2 #011-e IF_METRIC=10
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken dhclient[3685]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken dhclient[3685]: Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: All rights reserved.
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken kernel: [  143.552575] r8169 0000:02:02.0 eth2: link down
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken kernel: [  143.552602] r8169 0000:02:02.0 eth2: link down
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken kernel: [  143.552903] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken dhclient[3685]: Listening on LPF/eth2/80:1f:<snip>
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: Listening on LPF/eth2/80:1f:<snip>
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: Sending on   LPF/eth2/80:1f:<snip>
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken ifup[3670]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xb7272453)
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken dhclient[3685]: Sending on   LPF/eth2/80:1f:<snip>
Mar  7 15:18:32 ken dhclient[3685]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xb7272453)
Mar  7 15:18:33 ken boinc[1160]: No protocol specified
Mar  7 15:18:34 ken boinc[1160]: No protocol specified
Mar  7 15:18:34 ken ntpd[1996]: Deleting interface #4 eth2, 2a02:c7f:<snip>#123, interface stats: received=35, sent=36, dropped=0, active_time=97 secs
Mar  7 15:18:34 ken ntpd[1996]: Deleting interface #5 eth2, fe80::821f:<snip>%2#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=97 secs
Mar  7 15:18:35 ken dhclient[3685]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xb7272453)
Mar  7 15:18:35 ken ifup[3670]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xb7272453)
Mar  7 15:18:36 ken kernel: [  146.957197] r8169 0000:02:02.0 eth2: link up
Mar  7 15:18:36 ken kernel: [  146.957212] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth2: link becomes ready
Mar  7 15:18:37 ken ntpd[1996]: unable to create socket on eth2 (6) for fe80::821f:<snip>%2#123
Mar  7 15:18:37 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth2.IPv6 with address fe80::821f:<snip>.
Mar  7 15:18:37 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: New relevant interface eth2.IPv6 for mDNS.
Mar  7 15:18:37 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Registering new address record for fe80::821f:<snip> on eth2.*.
Mar  7 15:18:39 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth2.IPv6 with address fe80::821f:<snip>.
Mar  7 15:18:39 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth2.IPv6 with address 2a02:c7f:<snip>.
Mar  7 15:18:39 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Registering new address record for 2a02:c7f:<snip> on eth2.*.
Mar  7 15:18:39 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::821f:<snip> on eth2.
Mar  7 15:18:40 ken ntpd[1996]: Listen normally on 7 eth2 [2a02:c7f:<snip>]:123
Mar  7 15:18:40 ken ntpd[1996]: Listen normally on 8 eth2 [fe80::821f:<snip>%2]:123
Mar  7 15:18:42 ken dhclient[3685]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0xb7272453)
Mar  7 15:18:42 ken ifup[3670]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0xb7272453)
Mar  7 15:18:42 ken dhclient[3685]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.13 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x532427b7)
Mar  7 15:18:42 ken ifup[3670]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.13 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x532427b7)
Mar  7 15:18:42 ken ifup[3670]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.13 from 192.168.0.1
Mar  7 15:18:42 ken ifup[3670]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.13 from 192.168.0.1
Mar  7 15:18:42 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth2.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.13.
Mar  7 15:18:42 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: New relevant interface eth2.IPv4 for mDNS.
Mar  7 15:18:42 ken avahi-daemon[1401]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.13 on eth2.IPv4.
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken boinc[1160]: No protocol specified
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: bound to 192.168.0.13 -- renewal in 36499 seconds.
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: ifconfig eth2 mtu 7152
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: /bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/clamav-freshclam-ifupdown
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ifmetric
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: Configuring interface eth2=eth2 (inet6)
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: /bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/bridge
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
Mar  7 15:18:43 ken ifup[3670]: /sbin/modprobe -q net-pf-10 > /dev/null 2>&1 || true # ignore failure.
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: /sbin/sysctl -q -e -w net.ipv6.conf.eth2.accept_ra=2
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: /sbin/sysctl -q -e -w net.ipv6.conf.eth2.autoconf=1
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: /bin/ip link set dev eth2 up
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: /bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/clamav-freshclam-ifupdown
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ifmetric
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: /bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/clamav-freshclam-ifupdown
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ifmetric
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/sendmail
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ifup[3670]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken boinc[1160]: No protocol specified
Mar  7 15:18:44 ken ntpd[1996]: Listen normally on 9 eth2 192.168.0.13:123
```

I have Googled various phrases and terms but I have not found an answer. My problem appears similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/829230/failed-to-start-raise-network-interfaces-on-ubuntu-16-04-01), and may even be the same, but resorting to `nmcli` is my very last resort. I'd be happy to use `systemd` to configure my interfaces but I'd lose `sysv` compatibility (which I probably don't need anyway) and I'm irritated by the fact that other devices work happily with the `interfaces` file.

There are **so many** new configuration files with `systemd` that I cannot guess where to look to find out what is going on. I don't even know how to make anything verbose in `systemd`.

I am at a loss. Help!

Comment: Seen as I can't access my machine remotely when using wake-on-LAN I've had to bite the bullet and use `systemd-networkd`. Configuration is suprisingly easy and may be the better solution in the long run. This issue remains though so it's not an actual solution to this problem. I can easily revert the changes should a suggestion appear.